# How to send the record ID of the row the user pressed on edit button?

Tags: php, html

Substance ID saved to the session is the last record ID In the table
I need to send the record ID of the row the user pressed on edit button
each for every button selected the record ID sent is the last record ID in the table. moreover, the data table script is not working.

```
   <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
php
<div class="table-responsive">
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tableStock" style="width:100%">
    
    <thead>
    
      <tr>
        <th>Substance Name</th>
        <th>SubstanceCategory</th>
        <th>Substance Quantity</th>
        <th>Substance Price</th>
        <th>Branch Location</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    
    </thead>
    
    <?php while($row=$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $_SESSION["Substance_ID"] = $row['Substance_ID'];
      $_SESSION["Substance_Name"] = $row['Substance_Name'];
    ?>
    <tr>
      
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['Substance_Name'];?>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['Substance_Category']; ?>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['Substance_Quantity']; ?>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['Substance_Price']; ?>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <?php  
        if($row['Branch_ID']==0){
        echo "Lebanon"; }
        else{
        echo "Syria";
        } 
        ?>
      </td>
      
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="updateSAtockItems.php" role="button">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="production.html" role="button">Delete</a>
      </td>
      
    </tr>
    
    <?php } ?>
    
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
  
</div>

<script>
  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    });
    
</script>
     <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Page level plugins -->
  <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
  <script src="js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are overwriting your session values in a loop here, _of course_ only the last one “survives” that in the end. I don’t see what sense storing these IDs in the session is supposed to make here in the first place? If you want to provide a button to enable the user to edit _one_ specific record - then you should pass that ID as a parameter when that button is clicked. Involving sessions make rather little sense for that to begin with.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I just start learning php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the session variable is always the last ID in table is because you are updating it every on every row, and therefore the last value will remain.

You could use a form to send the data over as a POST request. Then in your relevant handler, i.e. `updateStockItems.php` you can use `$_POST['substance_ID']` to get which substance the user clicked on.

```
<td>

    <form action="updateStockItems.php" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" name="substance_ID" value="<?php echo $row['Substance_ID']; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</a>

    </form>

    <form action="production.html" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" name="substance_ID" value="<?php echo $row['Substance_ID']; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

    </form>

</td>
```

Your `.Datatable()` is being called on a selector which does not exist. You need to change `$('#dataTable')` to your table's ID, so `$('#tableStock').DataTable()`

Comment: thanks a lot, this solved the issue. yet i still need help in bootstrap datatable problem

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The search section does not appear. and the columns are not sortable.

Comment: You'll need to update the id in the jQuery selector. I've updated my answer

Comment: I just updated the code and its not working. though one more problem is solved. again thanks

Comment: Have you followed the installation guide https://datatables.net/manual/installation? This should run through the process of getting it all working. Are you sure there are no Javascript console errors? You're using `$` to invoke jQuery before you have linked the script. Try changing it to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){..`

Comment: I think that it's clear for you now that I am a beginner in the web development field. I followed the instructions in guide  datatables.net/manual/installation and there is some errors in the console. the error is  GET http://localhost/Azzam/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
util.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:55
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
stock.php:409 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at stock.php:409
(anonymous) @ stock.php:409

Comment: Don't worry, we all start somewhere. This has become more of a general question as you're now asking about adding scripts.
The 404 error means that the file you've linked to isn't there, so you need to look at whether that is correct first.
I would suggest looking at using the [https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html](CDN) which hosts the files you need.
You'll need the jQuery ones _and_ the datatables ones. Go to [https://cdnjs.com/](CDNJS) and search for both jQuery, and DataTables, and it will give you the links for grabbing the required files.